# What is the hidden trophy below Lore Master?

Tags: achievements, lucky-luna

In Lucky Luna's trophy list there is a hidden Story Mode trophy marked ??? near the bottom of the list. It sits between the trophies for Lore master and Taking flight. What are the requirements for this hidden trophy?

[image: Lucky Luna trophies]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's "Forge your own path":

[image]

It’s the last one when you unlock the alternative ending (when you have 100% of the blue pieces).